# Transparent Minicart Issue (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm having an issue where when I click or hover over the minicart at the top of the page that it appears transparent, I've got this store set up on a multi-site and don't have this problem with the other sites I have running even though the app and skin folders are basically copy and pasted from store to store,

[image: Minicart Non Opaque]

I haven't been able to find any help regarding this anywhere so any advice would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Looks like a z-index issue on the cart content without seeing the site it is very hard to determain the best way to tackle this